# How to configure Stocator on Amazon EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, stocator

I am trying to configure Stocator on an Amazon EMR cluster to access data on Amazon s3. I have found resources that indicate that this should be possible, but very little detail on how to get this to work.

When I start my EMR cluster I use the following config:

```
{
    "classification": "core-site",
    "properties": {
        "fs.stocator.scheme.list": "cos",
        "fs.cos.impl": "com.ibm.stocator.fs.ObjectStoreFileSystem",
        "fs.stocator.cos.impl": "com.ibm.stocator.fs.cos.COSAPIClient",
        "fs.stocator.cos.scheme":"cos"
    }
}
```

I then try to access a file using `cos://mybucket.service/myfile`

This yields an error due to missing credentials.

I add the credentials, in `spark-shell`, to the properties using:

```
val credentials = new com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain().getCredentials
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.cos.service.access.key",credentials.getAWSAccessKeyId)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.cos.service.secret.key",credentials.getAWSSecretKey)
```

Now when I try to access `cos://mybucket.service/myfile` I get the error: `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist:`.

accessing the file using `s3://mybucket/myfile` works, as it doesn't use Stocator. Also accessing the file via the amazon CLI works.

Are there any online resources detailing how to get `Stocator` working on `AWS`?

Has anyone successfully done this themselves, and can you share your configuration?

Answer (score -1):

1. You may want to just contact Gil Vernik and ask for advice. Do make sure that it works with the EMR S3 consistency semantics; I believe it should.
2. Hadoop 3.1 has its own [high performance committers](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/site/markdown/tools/hadoop-aws/committers.md), probably faster than Stocator. (but I [would say that](http://steveloughran.blogspot.co.uk/2017/09/stocator-high-performance-object-store.html), wouldn't I?)
3. And part of the source for that code came from the [Netflix S3A committer](https://github.com/rdblue/s3committer/).

I'd play with the netflix one as I'm confident it works well there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions I will investigate the other options available